# Vim multiple chain commands, first one uses range

Tags: vim

Some Vim functions work on a range:

```
:'<,'>TOhtml
```

What is the syntax for the first command taking a range, and the latter commands pipe the result?

In the comments on the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Multiple_commands_at_once) it suggests a plugin to allow the range to be run on by all the commands; but here I only need the first argument to handle the range.

```
# These are the commands I am attempting to chain
:'<,'>TOhtml
:w! ~/mylink
:q!

# The last two can chain or be one command
:w! ~/mylink | q!
:wq! ~/mylink

# But these fail
:'<,'>TOhtml | wq! ~/mylink
:execute "'<,'>TOhtml" | "wq! ~/mylink"
```

Comment: I am confused that ":help :|" specifically says ":write !" cannot be followed by another Vim command, but I followed it with ":q!"

Comment: `:write !` is not the same as `:write!`; see `:h :_!`.

Comment: Go excited that I could write :'<,'>TOhtml !w! ~/mylink , oh well =/

Comment: @ClothSword what was the `!w!` ? my understanding is you were invoking external `w` command?

Comment: and how about `.....|wq! file` or `...|x! file` ?

Comment: @Kent according to :h :_! I can put a space and an exclamation mark and pass the result forwards to command "w!"... ah so its an external command. Derp.

Comment: Mapping for .vimrc (for some reason the q! needs to be separate): vmap <F1> :TOhtml<CR>:w! ~/mylink<CR>:q!<CR>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `execute` is the way to go, but you only have to quote the command for `:execute`, not the second one.

That is, replace:

```
:execute "'<,'>TOhtml" | "wq! ~/mylink"
```

With this:

```
:execute "'<,'>TOhtml" | wq! ~/mylink
```

Answer (score 2):

ClothSword, you are not far off the mark. Depending on your VIM settings, there are three expressions that could potentially be used to chain multiple commands on a single line: `|`, `\|` and `<bar>`, as in:

```
:echom "test 1" | echom "OK"
:echom "test 2" \| echom "OK"
:echom "test 3" <bar> echom "OK"
```

The way to test which one of them would work for you, would be to run all three of the above commands, followed by `:messages`. In the output, you should see error messages for the commands that didn't work: Invalid exprecion, Undefined variable, etc... the actual error message is irrelevant. While, for the command that did work, you will see two lines of the output, similar to:

```
test [number]
OK
```

There are a couple of pitfall to watch out for when using command chaining:

1. `|` behaves differently to what I described above when used to chain multiple system commands, eg: `:read !ls | wc`
2. care must be taken when used with `:g`, `:s` and `:map` commands as it may not do what you expect, eg: `:%g/foo/p|>`, `:%s/foo/bar/|>` or `:nmap 10\| map \ l`

**NOTE:** You could also use `<NL>` in the same way you use `|` (can be inserted with `Ctrl-V` `Ctrl-J`, which will output `^@`). However, this usage is not recommended as it is more inline with chaining external commands.

**SEE ALSO:** If you want to get a full picture on how command chaining works in VIM then I would recommend you read VIM's manual on :bar (`:help :bar`) and have a look at the `b` flag of the cpoption (`:help cpoption`).

Comment: What settings determine what you use?